# Cannot run program "su" on rooted device

Tags: android, root, android-permissions, su

I have a rooted phone running Android N (AOSP build). I am trying to get root permissions from my app but it keeps getting permission denied. Here is what I am trying:

```
java.lang.Process p = runtime.exec("su");
                DataOutputStream commandLine = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
                commandLine.writeBytes("rm /data/local/tmp/testfile\n");
                commandLine.flush();
                p.waitFor();
```

However, it keeps failing with the error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:983)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:691)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:524)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:421)
W/System.err:     at MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:104)
```

I have also added `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` to my manifest but that does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried moving the app to the system/priv-app folder?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider running the su process in this way:

```
ProcessBuilder mProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
                                   .command("/system/xbin/su")
                                   .redirectErrorStream(true).start();

OutputStream out = mProcess.getOutputStream();
```